# What is resting elevation in android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-elevation

I am little bit confused with the term "resting elevation." I know what is elevation in android material design environment but couldn't exactly know what is resting elevation. Is it the zero elevation of a material (i.e.) it is not having any elevation?

Thanks in advance for any help regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to material design, all view components must have a default elevation which would be the same across apps. This is known as resting elevation. In other words, it is the elevation that a view will have when it's resting.
For example the resting elevation of a floating action button is 6dp. It will increase when a user taps on it and will go back to resting elevation once the tap is over.

Refer [Elevation and shadows](https://m1.material.io/material-design/elevation-shadows.html) for more info.

Comment: refer not found 404